# Powershell - Unable to find type [System.Windows.Controls.TextBox]

Tags: .net, powershell, assemblies

I'm struggling to figure out why PS is unable to find the correct assemblies. I've tried various combinations of Add-Type and Reflection.Assembly but nothing seems to change. I feel like I'm doing something fundamentally wrong but I have no clue what to try next. I've also tried using the `-LiteralPath` parameter and putting in the location of the .dll file but the error always stays the same: *"Unable to find type [System.Windows.Controls.TextBox]"*. What am I missing here?

This is run on Server2016 with the following PS version:

[image]

```
Add-Type -Name PresentationFramework
#Add-Type -Name System.Controls
#[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("PresentationFramework")
#[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Controls")
#[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
#[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

class TextBoxControl{

    [System.Windows.Controls.TextBox] $TextBox
    [String] $Name

    TextBoxControl ([String] $Name, [System.Windows.Controls.TextBox] $TextBox )
    {
        $This.TextBox = $TextBox
        $This.Name = $Name
    }


    [String] GetName(){
        Return $This.Name
    }

    [String] GetValue(){
        Return $This.TextBox.Text
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The WinForms' TextBox namespace reference is wrong, because you're mixing WPF with Windows Forms by importing assemblies of PresentationFramework (WPF), System.Windows.Forms (WinForms).

Which platform do you want to use actually?

If you want to use WinForm's TextBox, then you must change your code. 
Update current code:

```
[System.Windows.Controls.TextBox] $TextBox
```

to

```
[System.Windows.Controls.Forms.TextBox] $TextBox
```

Comment: I want to use WPF. I am using XAML files for the UI.

Comment: Then you should not use/reference to Winforms. Use only System.Windows.Controls namespace in `PresentationFramework.dll` assembly.

Comment: I'm confused. Which parts reference Windows Forms? What changes do I need to make to the code so the errors go away? The constructor expects parameter of type [System.Windows.Controls.TextBox] but I get "unable to find type" errors. I have 'Add-Type -Name PresentationFramework' at the very top but it still can't find the type.